# The function does not connect with the query to the database

Tags: php

I am using a function that is supposed to get the result row as an associative array but it does not get me because it changes from mysql to mysqli according to the moderator's instructions.

What am I doing wrong

```
function dbquery($link,$query) {

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query );
    if (!$result) {
        echo mysqli_connect_error();
        return false;
    } else {
        return($result);

    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Function to connect to the database

```
function dbconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
    global $db_connect;
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($db_connect, $db_name);
    if (!$db_connect) {
        die("<div style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;text-align:center;'><b>Unable to establish connection to MySQL</b><br />".mysqli_connect_error()." : ".mysqli_connect_error()."</div>");
    } elseif (!$db_select) {
        die("<div style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;text-align:center;'><b>Unable to select MySQL database</b><br />".mysqli_connect_error($db_name)." : ".mysqli_connect_error()."</div>");
    }

}
$link = dbconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

What is wrong ??

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: siteurl in
>   **/home/sfera/public_html/locale/Polish-utf8/global.php** on line
>   **132**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: siteurl in
>   **/home/sfera/public_html/locale/Polish-utf8/global.php** on line
>   **140**
>  
>  **Notice**:  Undefined index: siteurl in
>   **/home/sfera/public_html/locale/Polish-utf8/global.php** on line
>   **147**

You know how to remove this error the error is from the locale. I will show you that you know what's going on

```
    $locale['global_441'] = "Your account on ".$settings['sitename']."has been banned";
$locale['global_442'] = "Hello [USER_NAME],\n
Your account on ".$settings['sitename']." was caught posting too many items to the system in very short time from the IP ".USER_IP.", and have therefor been banned. This is done to prevent bots from submitting spam messages in rapid succession.\n
Please contact the site administrator at ".$settings['siteemail']." to have your account restored or report if this was not you causing this security ban.\n
".$settings['siteusername'];
// Lifting of suspension
$locale['global_450'] = "Suspension automatically lifted by system";
$locale['global_451'] = "Suspension lifted at ".$settings['sitename'];
$locale['global_452'] = "Hello USER_NAME,\n
The suspension of your account at ".$settings['siteurl']." has been lifted. Here are your login details:\n
Username: USER_NAME
Password: Hidden for security reasons\n
If you have forgot your password you can reset it via the following link: LOST_PASSWORD\n\n
Regards,\n
".$settings['siteusername'];
$locale['global_453'] = "Hello USER_NAME,\n
The suspension of your account at ".$settings['siteurl']." has been lifted.\n\n
Regards,\n
".$settings['siteusername'];
$locale['global_454'] = "Account reactivated at ".$settings['sitename'];
$locale['global_455'] = "Hello USER_NAME,\n
Last time you logged in your account was reactivated at ".$settings['siteurl']." and your account is no longer marked as inactive.\n\n
Regards,\n
```

It makes me an argument from the base though I have it in function

// Fetch the Site Settings from the database and store them in the $settings variable

```
$settings = dbarray(dbquery($link,"SELECT * FROM ".$db_prefix."setting"));
```

So this is but the locale do not want to read them

Comment: What error do you get? What debugging have you done? Have you tried to narrow it down to one function in particular not working? You should be able to do that.

Comment: I can not seem to find the issue just by looking at the code. What errors do you get? (if any at all)
Also, bonus tip, you do not have to put parentheses around your returned values, you just need to do `return $result`.

Comment: FYI, your `mysqli_close()` is never going to be called, because either your `if` or `else` cases are going to cause you to return before that.

Comment: I've tried everything already, and I have such a mistake

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/sfera/public_html/funkcje.php on line 103

Comment: Hey @Paul looks like you are missing the bit of code that calls dbquery() function, so can't really see what you're passing to it. I would consider doing `var_dump($link, $query); exit;` right after the function call to see what the values you are passing through.

Comment: Shows me
 NULL NULL

and such errors
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /home/sfera/public_html/funkcje.php on line 106

Notice: Undefined variable: query in /home/sfera/public_html/funkcje.php on line 116

Comment: As Carlos said, you need to show the code where you're actually calling `dbquery()` (as well as the code that assigned the variables passed to it).  Without seeing that, we can't really tell you anything that those errors aren't already saying.

Comment: So, because it gives you `NULL NULL` as the values, it means you are not actually calling your `dbquery()` method in the correct way. If possible, find where this function is called and edit your question so we can further assist you.

Comment: At the bottom I added a code where we use the dbquery function

Comment: As I can see you are only sending the `$query` part of the arguments to your `dbquery()` function, you are missing the first argument which is `$link` and according to the PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) you need to send in a "A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()".

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_connect_error()` should only be used to report errors that happen during `mysqli_connect()`. If you get an error while performing a query, you should use `mysqli_error()` to get that error.

Also, you're calling `mysqli_close($link);`. This was never executed because both branches of the `if` statement returned from the function. But you shouldn't close the link in this function, you're very likely to want to use the same link for other queries.

So the function should be:

```
function dbquery($link,$query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query );
    if (!$result) {
        echo mysqli_error($link);
        return false;
    } else {
        return($result);
    }
}
```

Similarly, `dbconnect()` should use `mysqli_error()` when reporting a failure of `mysqli_select_db()`. It also needs to return the connection instead of setting a global variable.

```
function dbconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($db_connect, $db_name);
    if (!$db_connect) {
        die("<div style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;text-align:center;'><b>Unable to establish connection to MySQL</b><br />".mysqli_connect_error()." : ".mysqli_connect_error()."</div>");
    } elseif (!$db_select) {
        die("<div style='font-family:Verdana;font-size:11px;text-align:center;'><b>Unable to select MySQL database $db_name</b><br />".mysqli_error($db_connect)." : ".mysqli_error($db_connect)."</div>");
    }
    return $db_connect;
}
```

You can also combine `mysqli_connect()` and `mysqli_select_db()`, as the database name can be specified as an additional argument to `mysqli_connect()`:

```
mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Comment: I am present but does not show me the contents from the tables

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've gathered here, your code needs to be changed to:

`$result = dbquery($link, "SELECT * FROM ".$db_prefix."product  ");`

Notice the `$link` variable is missing from your code posted above.

Comment: There's more to it than that.  Notice that the `dbconnect()` function isn't actually returning anything.

Comment: Ah, yes, good catch @PatrickQ, but let's see if he can get to sort his problem by doing this simple change. I am also wondering how he had `NULL NULL` on the params sent through, we need more code here :o

Comment: I have the same because I have a directory of locale and language packs in it and I have a mistake and I added a $link but nothing has changed

Comment: As Patrick mentioned above the following line makes `$link` be `NULL`: `$link = dbconnect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);` However, your `dbconnect()` function is actually using the global `$db_connect` so instead of using `$link`, do `dbquery($db_connect, $query)`.

Answer (score -2):

Not use MySQL or MySQLi. Use PDO:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
$db_hostname = "localhost";
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "XXXXXX";
#error_reporting(0);
#error_reporting(E_ALL);
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
try {
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_hostname;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: It's reasonable to use PDO as a matter of standards, but your answer would be better if you explained _why_ he should use PDO.

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Comment: If you want to suggest that the OP uses PDO, feel free to do so as a comment.  However, what you have posted doesn't actually address the problem that the OP is having, and therefore isn't really an answer and could potentially garner downvotes.

Comment: To sum up, both are safe, but PDO supports multiple databases.